# Is there a statistically robust stock market history generator?

Tags: time-series, monte-carlo, finance

I want to use some numerical and Monte Carlo techniques in computer code to estimate probabilities of various complex stock index price movements.

I want to do this with randomly generated price time series, partly because I believe the real stock market history is not long enough to yield reliable results, and partly to avoid over-fitting my algorithms to the real data (yes, these two concerns are somewhat correlated).

Is there a random price history generator out there that can mimic, say, the S&P 500 Index?

At the risk of over-defining the problem... if I gave a researcher or a practitioner two vectors representing price histories with matching starting and ending prices, and asked them to identify which one is real and which one is generated, they would not be able to tell except by looking up the actual historical series.

Comment: I wonder if this would get more attention at the quantitative finance Stack: quant.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Maybe. Is there a way to move the post?

Comment: This sounds, to me, like a Reinforcement Learning Environment Generation problem; the RL environment would try very hard to mimic the real stock market conditions, which in your case can be applied onto the raw, artificial price history (stock price is just `random walk` and a robust wiener process generator should give you a raw price process); the conditions include splits, dividends, big news, corporate actions, et certera.